# How to disable auto-rotation in jwplayer library?

Tags: android, jwplayer, jwplayer6, jwplayer7

How to disable auto-rotation in jwplayer library?

`fragment.setFullscreenOnDeviceRotate(false);

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

android:screenOrientation="landscape"           android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>`

not wokring.

I want to start with the Activity, orientation was landscape, including jwplayer

[Video](http://rgho.st/private/7nBBwgyks/626e05c4327506f5ab515a73736097ec)

Comment: I added a video. orientation landscape and  2 second auto change orientation port.why is this happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Add Screen orientation in AndroidManifest.xml

<activity
        android:name=".GalleryAlbumsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_image_gallery_albums"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
I did all steps described here and nothing works for me, but I found a solution:

```
fragment.setFullscreenOnDeviceRotate(true)
playerView = fragment.player
playerView.setFullscreen(playerView.fullscreen, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to the `<activity>` element in the manifest.

Can you show us maybe some parts of your code to help us solving your problem?

Comment: I had already done . no Results,


What exactly needs to throw the code ?

Comment: What do you mean? Here's how the <activity> element in your AndroidManifest.xml should look like: 
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="MainActivityHeading"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

Edit: If the orientation should be always landscape, you should replace "portrait" with "landscape" ;)

Comment: There is not so simple .

I say that the use jwplayer library. Did you enjoy it ?

Comment: Sorry mate, I don't understand your question.. Maybe someone else can help you :)

Comment: I added a video. orientation landscape and  2 second auto change orientation port.why is this happening ?